# PhoneGap + MCCordovaPlugin where should ic_notification image be placed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, phonegap

Trying to do a simple PhoneGap build with MCCordovaPlugin.
Keep getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordova.MCInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Missing required properties: notificationCustomizationOptions**

```
<preference name="**com.salesforce.marketingcloud.app_id**" value="xxx" />
<preference name="**com.salesforce.marketingcloud.access_token**" value="xxx" />
<preference name="**com.salesforce.marketingcloud.tenant_specific_endpoint**" value="https://xxx.device.marketingcloudapis.com/" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" version="2.4.1"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" version="4.0.1"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" version="2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" version="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" version="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" source="npm" version="2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="3.0.0" />

<plugin name="**cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk**" spec="**6.2.1**" />

<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />

    <!-- required by Firebase FCM Marketing Cloud: cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated -->
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />

    <!-- required by Salesforce Marketing Cloud: cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk -->
    <preference name="**com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notification_small_icon**" value="**ic_notification**" />

</platform>
```

Where is ic_notification.png supposed to be in the project hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

You need to map the image in your config.xml such that it (all density versions) will end up in the correct the Android app `res` folder.

For example:
If I store my notification icons (ic_notification.png) in density dependent folders (`/res/android/drawable-{DENSITY}/ic_notification.png`) then I would need to map those images like this:

```xml
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
  <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-mdpi/ic_notification.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_notification.png" />
  <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_notification.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_notification.png" />
  <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-xhdpi/ic_notification.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_notification.png" />
  <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_notification.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_notification.png" />

  <preference name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notification_small_icon" value="ic_notification" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97425/discussion-on-answer-by-seth-phonegap-mccordovaplugin-where-should-ic-notifica).

Comment: adding this line got me over the exception; `<resource-file src="res/android/drawable/ic_notification.png"        target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_notification.png" />`